# Wrong window buttons color with a custom theme

Tags: gnome, nautilus, themes, svg

I'd like to make a custom theme for Ubuntu 16.04.

Searching for the best method, I decided to use the Radiance theme (included in Ubuntu) and modify icons and stuff...

I'm trying to replace the original `.svg` files with custom ones, these ones are accepted by the W3C validator, and are perfectly editable and viewable in Adobe Illustrator and Inkscape, they are even viewable by the nautilus file explorer included in Ubuntu, but they just don't work and Ubuntu displays those from the high-contrast theme.

What am I doing wrong? Or what do they need to be usable?

The image shows Comparison of how it is, and how I want to be:
[image: Comparison of how it is, and how I want to be]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happened to me, Ubuntu usually change the files' permissions. Have you tried running `chmod -R 777 theme_folder_path`?